# Solving a fractional programming problem with square root of quadratic function in denominator

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms

I am trying to solve following problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x\in\Re^{n\times1}} &\frac{x^\top H x + f^\top x + C_e}{\sqrt{x^\top R x + C_v}}\\
\text{s.t.} &~~Ax\leq b
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $H$ and $R$ are both positive semidefinite matrics. both $C_e$ and $C_v$ are positive scalar.

I know that if there is NO "square root" in denominator, we could let $z^2=\frac{1}{x^\top R x + C_v}$ and $x=y/z$, then the quadratic fractional problem can be transferred into a non-convex QCQP problem about $z$ and $y$.

Does anyone know how to deal with "square root of quadratic funcion" in denominator? Many thanks!!

Comment: What do you know of $f$? Namely if it is such that the numerator is non-negative one could square the whole cost function.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks! f’x is always negative, I don’t think square root of both numerator & denominator is a good idea, because x’Rx + Cv is much larger than x’Hx + f’x + Ce. You can think numerator is the expectation of f(x) and the denominator is the standard deviation of f(x).

Comment: Have you tried just throwing it in a nonlinear optimizer, local, or perhaps global? Depending on the size and input data,it could be easy to solve, even to global optimality.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone emm...... IPOPT will be my last resort

Comment: I assume that $f^\top x$ is always negative due to the inequality constraints $A\,x\leq b$? But this doesn't answer whether the numerator is always non-negative or not. Is the following matrix positive semi-definite: $$\begin{bmatrix}H & \frac{1}{2} f \\ \frac{1}{2} f^\top & C_e\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen $x$ is always positive, $f^\top x < 0$ and Yes, the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}H & \frac{1}{2}f \\ \frac{1}{2}f^\top & C_e \end{bmatrix}$$ is positive definite. As I said, I am able to solve the problem $$\begin{aligned}
\min_{x} &\frac{x^\top H x + f^\top x + C_e}{x^\top R x + C_v}\\
\text{s.t.} &~~Ax\leq b
\end{aligned}.$$ The reason I need the square-root in the demoninator is because  $x^\top R x + C_v$ is much larger than $x^\top H x + f^\top x + C_e$.

Comment: So you only added the square root is because the denominator is too big otherwise? To me this doesn't really sounds like the right reason when constructing a cost function. If you are worried about numerically accuracies you could either multiply the numerator by a big scalar or multiply the denominator by a small scalar. Either should not change the location of the optimum. However, adding a square root to only the denominator (or numerator for that matter) in most cases would alter to location of the optimum.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what problem you are really trying to solve, because I have the feeling we are dealing with a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).